# SslStream .NET Class communicate with Java

Tags: java, .net, sockets, c++-cli, sslstream

I have a .NET SSL server that use SslStream class to communicate with clients.

Does anyone know if this class can communicate with sockets of other languages like Java or only with .NET ?

Thanks.

----- EDIT ----

It works.

Comment: What makes you think that a protocol implementation (SSL) is language specific? The question makes just as much sense as to ask if a text file written by a .NET application can be read by a Java application.

Comment: Because sslstream class is based on windows socket.